# Flush IntelliJ cached directories

Tags: intellij-idea, tfs

I have just started using IntelliJ, and I made an unsuccessful attempt at checking out a remote repository. I am trying to check out the code again into the same local directory, but IntelliJ keeps telling me that the directory is already in use.

I have deleted the config in IntelliJ, and deleted and recreated the local directory, but that doesn't seem to solve the issue.

How can I flush out these cached directories so that I can try my checkout again?

Comment: What do you mean by "the directory is already in use"? What message exactly are you getting?

Comment: This is the error message that I am getting:

The following errors occurred during checkout:
Cannot create workspace '3.8.0'. The workspace folder C:\TFS\SIS is already in use by the workspace CN101537; Jitterbug on computer CN101537

Comment: This is a TFS error, it has nothing to do with IntelliJ cached directories. You need to sort out your TFS settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by going through the setup wizard and deleting the offending configurations. Once deleted I closed IntelliJ and re-opened it (probably overkill). I was then able to check out my code into the directory that I wanted.